# how can i access a property in an object /_text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to access the values of _text in the IdList but can't
This is my data : the data is of type object, the IdList is an object

```
query
eSearchResult:
Count: {_text: '203374'}
IdList:
Id: Array(20)
0:
_text: "34983115"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
_text: "34983114"
[[Prototype]]: Object
2:
_text: "34983113"
[[Prototype]]: Object
3:
_text: "34983112"
```

and this is my code: i get only **the keys: index ** back and **can not access the _text values**

```
  {Object.keys(query).length &&
        Object.keys(query.eSearchResult.IdList.Id).map((keyName, index) => {
          return (
              <div className="card-block" keyy={index}>
                {index}
                {index._text}
                {Object.keys(index).map((key, i) => {
                  return (
                    <div>
                      <td key={i}>
                        heyy key: {i}
                        {index[key]._text}
                      </td>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
       
          );
        })}
```

Comment: query does not seem to be an object

Comment: it is an object